# changing category name in WordPress from admin panel requires changing in codes

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing a theme for WordPress, so to show posts from specific category I used `wp_query()` function to specify the category. like this:

```
 $slogan = new wp_query(
                        array(
                                'category_name' => "hero_slider",
                                'title' => "slogan"
                            )
                    );
```

so when I rename the **hero_slider** category from admin panel there is need to change this code in the file to update category name.
please help me how to show posts in a theme so that the changing category names don't need to changing the code. thanks!

Comment: use the category id?

Comment: get current category slug?

Comment: how to get category id?

Comment: you go to the category and edit it, in the url you will see something like `&tag_ID=1` the value 1 is the id of the edited category

Comment: yes!! I founded it! thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the category id,its unique, doesn't alter if you modify the category :)

```
array(
'cat'   => $cat_id,
'title' => "slogan"
)
```

Comment: what about using widgets?

Comment: @Mohandes what widgets got to do with this question?

Comment: I don't know! actually this is my question.

Comment: @Mohandes no , your question is on this page and i don't see any mention of a widget

Comment: but it might be possible by creating a new widget. :\

Comment: just want to know is it possible to use widgets for this or not. :)

Comment: you can create a custom widget, yes

Answer (score 0):

Use the category id, for reference visit [Link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/)

or change to this as shown above by [madalinivascu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1906356/madalinivascu) `array(
'cat'   => $cat_id,
'title' => "slogan"
)`

Hope it helps

Comment: did you read the text in the red box of the page you supplied?